# using a form variable with a file upload script

Tags: php, html, forms

I am using this form as a file upload form(as part of a larger php script, $pk is sanitized in the actual thing):

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET["pk"]))
 { $pk = $_GET["pk"];}
echo '<form action="up.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="pk" value="$pk">
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>';
?>
```

I am using the following(extremely trimmed) code to handle the upload. Any syntax errors are a result of the tabifier I used.

```
<?php
 if (isset($_GET["pk"])) {
    $pk = $_GET["pk"];
}
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","x","x", "x");
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "./" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
echo "Stored in: " . "./" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$fileQuery = "INSERT INTO FILES VALUES (?, ?)";
if ($fileInsert = $con->prepare($fileQuery)) {
    $fileInsert->bind_param("ss", $pk, $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $fileInsert->execute();
    $fileInsert->close();
} else {
    print_r($con->error);
}
?>
```

What I would like to know, is how do I access $pk. Is it already passed to the handling code with the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion: `$pk` is not set.

So try to use `$_REQUEST['pk']` instead of `_GET`

Also, the single quotes in your echo won't evaluate $pk. Alter

```
input type="hidden" name="pk" value="$pk"
```

to

```
input type="hidden" name="pk" value="' . $pk . '"
```

Cheers, T.

Comment: so in the handling code, I should have  if (isset($_REQUEST["pk"])) {
    $pk = $_REQUEST["pk"]; ?

Comment: @Joshxtothe4: is your handling code different from the code that produces the form?

Comment: yes, i basically have form.php and upload.php. pk is passed to form.php from one page, and then i want it passed along with the file to upload.php, where both the filename and pk will be placed into a db record.

Comment: @Joshxtothe4: yes, use it that way. (or use $_POST)
You may also want to initialize `$pk` if it's not set ;) But you don't have to.

Comment: When I try to echo out $pk, using either POST or REQUEST, nothing is present.

Comment: ;) fine. If nothing is presented, it means there is nothing to present :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$_POST['pk']
```

but you'll see `$pk` I guess, because you're using single quotes to echo the string.

Comment: so in the handling code, should I have (isset($_POST["pk"])) {
    $pk = $_POST["pk"]; ?